# What is some good reference for tensor network?

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-information, resource-recommendations, quantum-entanglement, tensor-network

I am a physicist who is now doing some research in quantum information, which might involve tensor network.

Comment: There is a huge literature on the subject. Can you be more specific?

Comment: A general introduction will do Maybe more about calculation of e.g. ground state wavefunction or partition function

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/404450/2451

Answer (score 1):

Practical introduction to MPS (matrix product states) and PEPS (projected entangled pair states): https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.2164

Introduction to tensor networks, quantum information, some common algorithms using tensor networks: https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.03039

If you want to code algorithms and in general anything to do with tensor networks and specifically matrix product states: https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.3477

Tensor networks for lattice gauge theories: https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.12838

Libraries for tensor networks: https://itensor.org/ (C++, Julia), https://tenpy.github.io/ (Python)

I have also written an introductory paper on tensor networks, matrix product states and the quantum 1D Ising model where I explain my implementation of the variational ground state search algorithm in Julia: https://takisangelides.wixsite.com/personal/academic-projects (First paper on page),

Code for the above paper: https://github.com/TakisAngelides/Schwinger-Wilson-MPS